# Thermal expansion of a Hollow shaft

Tags: thermal-expansion

Hi I am designing bearings for the Paddle dryer assembly with an inclined hollow shaft. Although I have calculations for a solid steel shaft, unable to find reference of thermal expansion for  a hollow cylinder shaft. Please review and let me know.

Comment: A goggle search for "expansion of hollow shafts" gives as one of the first results: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thin-circular-ring-radius-temperature-change-d_1612.html